# Add a delay before sound is played

Tags: javascript, audio

I've got a bit of Javascript to play an audion on clicking an element:

```
    const btn1 = document.querySelectorAll(".btn-sound-1");
    let audio1 = new Audio('https://nullsieben.co.uk/74.mp3');

    btn1.forEach(btn => {
        btn.addEventListener("click", () => {
            audio1.play();
        });
    });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/wjq0ydhz/

I'd like to add the following:

1. Delay from clicking the button until the mp3 starts paying
2. Is there a way with this code to pre-load the sound so that it definately will when it's supposed to, regardless of bandwidth etc.?

Comment: for the delay, just wrap your play call in a `setTimeout(audio1.play,100);` or `setTimeout(function(){audio1.play()},100);`

Comment: For #2, have a look at audio events: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/audio#events

Comment: Is the reason for wanting the delay because you want to give the audio time to buffer? If so, you don't need that and can just configure the `audio` element with the `preload` attribute.

Comment: Reason for adding the delay not buffering, but that is that the button also starts an animation and the sound needs to play at a certain point.